# Very Simple "SELECT * FROM" Times Out (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, query-performance

Hello everyone and sorry for what may be a silly question, but I'm completely dazzled.

First thing is that I'm not sure that it's related to InnoDB, but I've tried this on MariaDB and on MySQL and results are the same.

Let's cut to the chase:

I have huge performance issues in the most unpredictable places. To illustrate it best, here is an example:

I have a table called 'image' which stores images as BLOBs as well as the images metadata like `image_name` or `DPI`. It's relatively small (~14000 rows) and most images are 250-1000 KB. In the example I will use `LOWER()` to get rid of index that I have on `image_name` column.

```
SELECT id FROM image WHERE LOWER(image_name) = 'img_0209.jpg'
```

This is super fast, at worst couple milliseconds, we got result `id = 1`.

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE id = '1'
```

This is fast again, most time spent transferring BLOB to me, no surprise (in the end, it's PRIMARY key).

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE LOWER(image_name) = 'img_0209.jpg'
```

**Now this thing is just refuses to execute. And I mean it. In 95% of the cases I will receive a timeout and occasionally it will execute after 10 minutes or so.**

`EXPLAIN SELECT` obviously tells me that it's simple `SELECT`. And I cannot run `SHOW PROFILES` because the request is never completed, so I cannot even think of where I can start debugging it.

Comment: I've never known a database giving a timeout, unless there was a firewall or antivirus in between me and the database, that cut the connection when seeing a specific kind of data passing.  But since the same image does pass now and then, you'd think there must be something else.  If you tried it with MariaDB too (or MySQL too), how was the data transfered to the other database?  I'm asking to see if you could have disk problems.  What is your storage and OS?

Comment: It's timeout as well from localhost, so it's for sure not related to firewall or anything like that. HDD is in perfectly healthy condition, I've used ESF Migration trial just to check if problem is MariaDB specific. OS: Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Was ESF Migration involved in creating the original database (the MariaDB, I suppose?).  Can you add the DDL for the image table?  What activity do you see on your system during the wait?

Comment: No (yes). Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/TrqYKE1E
Almost none (2% CPU, ususal stuff. Remember, it's one image).

Comment: Some kind of lock?  What kind of message do you get when there is a timeout?  What does MariaDB report in the logs?  What client is issuing the "select *"?  I'm asking since I wonder how a longblob would be displayed.

Comment: Why do you use `LOWER()`? Did you try with `WHERE image_name = 'img_0209.jpg'` and what was the performance?

Comment: Also, show us the `EXPLAIN` outputs of the queries (at least the 1st and 3rd).

Comment: Gerard: Timeout is timeout. It means no message whatsoever. How it is displayed depends on what I am using to connect to DB. In case of phpMyAdmin, it either un-logins you because 1440 seconds (default) passed, or there is a timeout in php, it actually depends on your settings.

In case of C#, it's System.Net.WebException. Either way, it means that there is nothing received in response within specified timeframe.

Comment: ypercube: I listed the reason in the body. My goal is not to make one specific request work, but to find out the reason why it's so slow. This is not the only place where I have to divide requests into parts (request IDs, then SELECT * for these IDs). This just happens to be the most transparent example.

Comment: You still haven't provided the EXPLAIN outputs. `WHERE lower(column) = ..` can still use the index, just not so effectively as `WHERE col = ..`. In any case, the problems might be due to inefficient plans or locking/blocking from other queries. 10+ min for a query from such a small table suggests it's not an index issue. But please provide more details so others can help you.

Comment: Because, however obnoxious as I may sound, that *"EXPLAIN SELECT obviously tells me that it's simple SELECT."* doesn't help me. Can we please see that EXPLAIN?

Comment: ypercube: Here is explain. https://pastebin.com/raw/4g31wp5h

Comment: Storing images in the database is a bad idea, especially in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, here are a few things you can try to get more info about the query in your case:

1. After starting the query, you can check its status by running

   ```sql
   SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
   ```
2. Also, you can try running the query on a smaller set of rows by adding another `where` predicate (covered by an index), for example:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM image WHERE id < 500 and LOWER(image_name) = 'img_0209.jpg'
   ```

---

As for why the query may be slow, I believe that what happens with the third query

```sql
SELECT * FROM image WHERE LOWER(image_name) = 'img_0209.jpg'
```

is that since the index can't be used, the engine does a full table scan and reads all the data for each row (including full BLOB data) and only then tries to filter them. So it probably reads a few GBs of data with that query.

Looking at the amount of data read from disc during the query may give some hints. You can try using the [`innodb_data_read`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_data_read) service status variable:

```sql
SET @read_metric = 'innodb_data_read';
SET @read_before = (
  SELECT variable_value
  FROM information_schema.session_status
  WHERE variable_name = @read_metric
);

SELECT * FROM image WHERE id < 500 and LOWER(image_name) = 'img_0209.jpg';

SET @read_after = (
  SELECT variable_value
  FROM information_schema.session_status
  WHERE variable_name = @read_metric
);

SELECT (@read_after - @read_before) / 1024 / 1024;
```

It should be similar to the size of data in BLOBs:

```sql
SELECT sum(length(image_data)) / 1024 / 1024 FROM image WHERE id < 500;
```

---

To speed up the query you need to avoid accesing BLOBs as much as possible. A few suggestions:

1. in your specific case changing the collation to an ignore-case one should help, so the `image_name` index may be used to find the single row you need
2. try using a self join to separate `image_name` and BLOBs access

   ```sql
   SELECT image_data.image_data
   FROM image
   JOIN image as image_data on image_data.id = image.id
   WHERE LOWER(image.image_name) = 'img_0209.jpg';
   ```
3. as described in the [Optimizing for BLOB Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/optimize-blob.html) manual, move the BLOBs to a separate table with just two colums: `id` and `data`

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will try this in the spare time. In the meantime we moved our database to MSSQL which doesn't have same issue (neither does Postgre in case anyone is wondering about free solutions)

Comment: MySQL' InnoDB moves large `TEXT`/`BLOB` columns to a separate place, somewhat like having a separate table.  This is automatic.

Comment: @RickJames, somewhat, but not.

You may want to read https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/ about BLOB storage in InnoDB.
The detail that is important here is: `MySQL internally has no optimizations to read portions of the blob – it is either read completely or not at all, so the 768 bytes on the row page is a little use – if BLOB is accessed external page will always have to be read`.

Also, there is a verified bug in MySQL which I think describes the same limitation: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58234

Comment: @Sergey - I think this is being partially addressed in MySQL 8.0, especially for JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Don't hide an indexed column inside a function (`LOWER`).  In this  case, have the collation be anything with `..._ci`, meaning case insensitive.  Then you can say simply say `WHERE image_name = 'img_0209.jpg'` *and* have `INDEX(image_name)`.  Now you don't have to search the entire table for that one row.

What will you do with the `BLOB` after you fetch it?  (There may be other optimizations there.)  About how many rows in the table?  (This may factor into the equation.)

**Specific suggestions**

```
ALTER TABLE `image`
    MODIFY COLUMN `image_name`
        varchar(80) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_general_ci
        DEFAULT NULL';
```

*and* remove the use of `LOWER()`:

```
WHERE image_name = 'img_0209.jpg'
```

Your existing index can stay unchanged (except that it will be rebuilt to handle the change in collation):

```
 UNIQUE KEY `image_name` (`image_name`)
```

Caveat:  The `ALTER` is likely to take a long time.

Comment: If you'd read the body, that's exactly what I was trying to do. Searching in non-indexed column yields exactly the same results.

Comment: `LOWER()` causes the query to be very slow.  Remove the function call.

Comment: @RickJames A) Would you suggest ALWAYS avoid LOWER() in SELECT specifications?  B) Could you provide an example of the suggestion from Mar 18, 2018 that uses the ..._ci technique using the query from the top of this question.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - I can't think of a case where `LOWER()` is better than `INDEX(name)` with `name VARCHAR(...) COLLATION ..._ci`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't select a longblob when your interface is a terminal.  The bytes of eg. an image may contain characters that are control characters for your interface or connection.

Comment: This is obviously not the case, otherwise SELECT * would never work.

Comment: Depends on what the image contains.  Just select a number of columns, apart from the image column.

Comment: Sure, you will get gibberish for an image blob; `SELECT ... HEX(imageblob) ...` would avoid it.  But this is irrelevant to the question about timing out.